# Tomcat doesn't save session information under eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, session-state

Trying to use sessions I came to this problem when I use this code:

```
<%@ page
    language="java"
    contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
   pageEncoding="UTF-8"

   import="java.util.Date"
%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta
            http-equiv="Content-Type"
            content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
        >
        <title>Session problem</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <%
        out.println("Are we using cookies? " + request.isRequestedSessionIdFromCookie() + "<BR>");      
        out.println("Are we using URL? " + request.isRequestedSessionIdFromURL() + "<BR>");     
        out.println("This is my session Id " + session.getId().toString() + "<BR>");
        out.println("It was created on: " + new Date(session.getCreationTime()) + "<BR>");
        out.println("The servlet context is: " + session.getServletContext().toString() + "<BR>");
        out.println("Is this session new? " + session.isNew() + "<BR><BR>");
    %>
    </body>
</html>
```

But everytime I hit reload it presents a new session Id, and the new property is always true. I looked for similar issues, and the most common problem is that cookies were not enabled, so I checked that my cookies were enabled.

Funny thing I uploaded the .war file, and in a test server it works nicely. So I deleted my tomcat server (7.0.22) from eclipse and from my hard drive and got a new one (7.0.34), and it didn't work either, the session information is still not saved.

I suspect something in the eclipse configuration, so the next step is to download a new Eclipse, I still use Eclipse Java EE Helios, and I might use a new version even when I am comfortable with this one, but I would be able to prevent this from happening again.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try using different browser clients (like firefox, opera, chrome)?